# Laravel 8 connect to MSSQL 2000 issue

Tags: php, laravel

OS: CentOS 7
DB: MSSQL 2000
Larvel: 8
PHP: 7.4.26

My project need to use Laravel 8 eloquent to connect to MSSQL 2000, MSSQL 2000 is too old to be connected by modern PHP SQL server driver, people suggest using ODBC + FreeTDS, so I take this [article](https://www.footmark.info/linux/centos/php5-pdo-mssql-centos7/) as a reference, I successfully connect to the SQL server by native PHP code via PDO, just like the example in that article.

```php
<?php

$host = '{IP}';
$port = '1433';
$dbname = '{DATABASE}';
$username = '{USERNAME}';
$password = '{PASSWORD}';

try {
    $dsn ='odbc:Driver=FreeTDS;Server=' . $host . ';Port=' . $port . ';Database=' . $dbname . ';UID=' . $username . ';PWD=' . $password . ';clientcharset=UTF-8';
    $dbConn = new PDO($dsn);
    $stmt = $dbConn->query("SELECT TOP 2 t.*
           FROM {DATABASE}.dbo.{TABLE} t
           WHERE CREATOR = '{SOMEONE}'
           ORDER BY CREATE_DATE DESC");
    $row = $stmt->fetchAll();
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($row);
    echo '</pre>';
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Then I go to [packagist](https://packagist.org/) to search ODBC package for Laravel and try:

- https://packagist.org/packages/yoramdelangen/laravel-pdo-odbc
- https://packagist.org/packages/cooperl/laravel-db2
- https://packagist.org/packages/abram/laravel-odbc
- https://packagist.org/packages/dbt/odbc-driver

Laravel was able to connect to the SQL server, but I got some error messages if has SQL condition:

```php
Table::where("CREATE_DATE", $this->date)
->orWhere("MODI_DATE", $this->date)
->get();
```

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 306 [FreeTDS][SQL Server]The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator. (SQLExecute[306] at /builddir/build/BUILD/php-7.4.26/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_stmt.c:259) (SQL: select * from "{TABLE}" where "{TABLE}"."CREATE_DATE" = 20060419 or "{TABLE}"."MODIFY_DATE" = 20060419)
```

I think it's not caused by the packages, but I try the SQL statement in native PHP with the same driver works perfectly, have no idea.

Comment: What are the column types of `CREATE_DATE` and `MODIFY_DATE`?

Comment: char 8, but it works in native PHP with PDO